# iOS WKWebView findString not selecting and scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, webkit, wkwebview

Since **iOS 14** WebKit supports [findString](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/3516409-findstring), but there is no documentation whatsoever yet.

However on the WWDC Sessions [Discover WKWebView enhancements](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiXvbyf4JrsAhWKxqQKHTWyB2wQFjAAegQIBBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%2Fwwdc2020%2F10188%2F&usg=AOvVaw24jw2bbeQMZesDOs2Ch1WM) they mention that is a basic functionality for "Find on Page", where you can find a string and the WebView will select it and scroll to center it.

It seems very easy to use and to be finding the string as I get a result of `matchFound` `true`, but there is no selection and there is no scrolling. Maybe I'm missing something?

This is the code I have tried:

```
let webView = WKWebView()
    
// ...
// after loading a website with the desired string on it.
// ...
    
webView.find("hello world") { result in
    print(result.matchFound) // true
}
```

Comment: I also found out that calling `webView.select(nil)` just before `webView.find("hello world")` it enables selection, but still no scrolling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update for iOS 16

On iOS 16 we have the new [UIFindInteraction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifindinteraction?changes=_2) API and now it is possible and very easy to do a *Find on Page* feature and search for a string.

```swift
myWebView.isFindInteractionEnabled = true
myWebView.findInteraction?.presentFindNavigator(showingReplace: false)
```

#### Important

This is not supported on macOS.

## Original Answer

So far I was only able to make it 'kind of working' combining with a bit of JavaScript.

```
let webView = WKWebView()
webView.select(nil)
webView.find("hello world") { result in
    guard result.matchFound else { return }
    webView.evaluateJavaScript(
        "window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect().top") { offset, _ in
        guard let offset = offset as? CGFloat else { return }
        webView.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(
            .init(x: 0,
                  y: offset + webView.scrollView.contentOffset.y,
                  width: 100,
                  height: 100), animated: true)
    }
}
```

Description:

1.
`webView.select(nil)` to make it first responder.
This is important otherwise when the match is found it won't be selected.

2.
`webView.find("my string")`

3.
If match is found use JavaScript to get the offset to the selected text.

4.
When receiving the offset scroll to it.